# node js, for-loop strange situation

Tags: arrays, node.js, for-loop

I'm trying to understand a situation that happened to me in node js, and I can't figure out why it happened.

Let's say I have the next code:

```
let obj = {x:1,y:2};
let arr = [obj, obj, obj, obj, obj], otherArr = [];
for(let i = arr.length - 1; i >=0; i--){
  let objInLoop = arr[i];

  if(objInLoop.x >= 0){   // <= this line throws an exception: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
    otherArr.push(objInLoop);
    delete arr[i];
  }
}
```

The error I get is in the 6th line of the code, The exception explains that the objInLoop is `undefined` and I can't understand how it could be.

It's obvious that I'm deleting an element from the array each cycle, but the loop start from the end so each `delete` doesn't supposed to effect the next cycle.

When I debugged that situation I saw that when the exception has been popped up, the `i` variable had a value that is less then the current `arr` length (The length had 1 element and the `i` shows 1 in the value.

This is not happened all the time, but it popped up couple of times and the `0` in the `if` condition is actually a variable that not always has true result for removing elements. All the code is much bigger and contains a lot of other functions and events. but the 'removing elements from the array' appears just in the for-loop section that I showed here. The other async code sections have a push function that add element to the array.

I know I can avoid it by adding a condition to the `if` that ensure that `objInLoop != undefined`. But the point is that I can't understand how can that exception happen.

Comment: AFAICT, it's unlikely to be because of the `delete`. It's almost certainly because you have a malformed object with no `x` property coming from somewhere. It's very likely to be a bug elsewhere in your code and not in the loop.

Comment: But the problem is not the `x`, the undefined is `arr[i]` and I also debugged it online, So I saw the situation which the length is less then `i`

Comment: Perhaps there's an error in the way the array is constructed and there is a gap in it?  Basically, the equivalent of doing this: `let arr = [obj, obj,, obj, obj], otherArr = [];`

Comment: Actually, a gap in the array is very likely if the array has gone through this loop before. You probably want to use splice() rather than delete().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will occur if there is a gap in the array. You can see this if you change your assignment of `arr` to `let arr = [obj, obj,, obj, obj], otherArr = [];`.

How can there be a gap in the array? Well, one thing that might cause it is if the array has gone through the loop previously and had stuff deleted.

```
let arr = [{}, {}, {}];
console.log(arr[1]); // {}
delete arr[1];
console.log(arr[1]); // undefined
console.log(arr); // [ {}, <1 empty item>, {} ]
```

If `delete` is what you really want and if the array might go through the loop more than once, then you will need to check for `undefined.`

Alternatively, you can use [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) if it's OK for an object's index to change.

```
let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
let i = 2;
arr.splice(i, 1); // remove one item at index i, i is 2, arr[i] is 'c'
console.log(arr); // ['a', 'b', 'd']
```

Or you can forgo the loop altogether and use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) depending on which is appropriate for your case.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used `splice` and it solved my problem. Perhaps `delete` is not the recommended way to delete elements on Arrays.